# iCloud warning does not go away

Tags: software-update, software

Apple keeps asking me to accept the new iCloud terms and conditions on my new iphone x. I have accepted the terms and conditions (many times) but the warning does not go away. Anyone that have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings, then tap on iCloud (where your name appears, above the option for Airplane Mode) and try signing back into your account.

Comment: But I am already signed into iCloud and the other services. Should I sign out and try to sign in again?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this apple support discussion on the matter:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8197483)

> It looks like you restored a backup to your iPhone X and since then
>   you're not able to accept updated iCloud Terms and Conditions. Let's
>   see if we can resolve this together. Here are some troubleshooting
>   steps to start with:
>
> First, make sure to restart your iPhone (if you haven't already.) --
>   Restart your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch
>
> Next, check and see if Restrictions are enabled on your device. -- Use
>   parental controls on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch
>
> If so, disable restrictions and try accepting the iCloud Terms and
>   Conditions again.
>
> If Restrictions are not enabled, or that step doesn't solve it, next
>   try signing out of iCloud. Once you're signed out, restart your
>   iPhone, and then sign back in to iCloud.